# python select columns based on row 0 value range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, range

From a Pandas DataFrame, I want to select columns where the value of the first row is between a certain range (e.g, 0.5 - 1.1)

I can select columns where row 0 is greater than or less than a certain number by doing this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(example).T

Result = df[df.iloc[:, 0] > 0.5].T
```

How do I do this for a range (i.e, greater than 0.5 and less than 1).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
print (df[df.iloc[:, 0].between(0.5, 1.1)])
```

Another solution with conditions with `&` (`array and`):

```
print (df[(df.iloc[:, 0] > 0.5) & (df.iloc[:, 0] < 1.1)])
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1.1,1.4,0.7,0,0.5]})
print (df)
     a
0  1.1
1  1.4
2  0.7
3  0.0
4  0.5

#inclusive True is by default
print (df[df.iloc[:, 0].between(0.5, 1.1)])
     a
0  1.1
2  0.7
4  0.5

#added inclusive False
print (df[df.iloc[:, 0].between(0.5, 1.1, inclusive=False)])
     a
2  0.7

print (df[(df.iloc[:, 0] > 0.5) & (df.iloc[:, 0] < 1.1)])
     a
2  0.7
```

But if need select columns by first row add `loc`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1.1,2,3],
                   'B':[.4,5,6],
                   'C':[.7,8,9],
                   'D':[1.0,3,5],
                   'E':[.5,3,6],
                   'F':[.7,4,3]})

print (df)
     A    B    C    D    E    F
0  1.1  0.4  0.7  1.0  0.5  0.7
1  2.0  5.0  8.0  3.0  3.0  4.0
2  3.0  6.0  9.0  5.0  6.0  3.0

print (df.loc[:, df.iloc[0, :].between(0.5, 1.1)])
     A    C    D    E    F
0  1.1  0.7  1.0  0.5  0.7
1  2.0  8.0  3.0  3.0  4.0
2  3.0  9.0  5.0  6.0  3.0

print (df.loc[:, df.iloc[0, :].between(0.5, 1.1, inclusive=False)])
     C    D    F
0  0.7  1.0  0.7
1  8.0  3.0  4.0
2  9.0  5.0  3.0

print (df.loc[:, (df.iloc[0, :] > 0.5) & (df.iloc[0, :] < 1.1)])
     C    D    F
0  0.7  1.0  0.7
1  8.0  3.0  4.0
2  9.0  5.0  3.0
```